# JPA findTopBy cannot work on spring boot 2.6.3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am studying spring-boot and JPA. the spring-boot version is 2.6.3, which is the latest current version.

I defined my entity class like:

```
@Entity
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    // ignore the getters, setters and toString()
```

And defined with one projection DTO interface.

```
public interface AuthorDto {

    public String getName();

    public int getAge();
}
```

then defined the repository as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {

    Author findFirstByGenre(String genre);
    AuthorDto findTopByGenre(String genre);
}
```

the method findFirstByXXX worked well, but the second method, `AuthorDto findTopByGenre(String genre);`, could not work well, and was ended up with the following error in the log:

```
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.bookstore.dto.AuthorDto com.bookstore.repository.AuthorRepository.findTopByGenre(java.lang.String)! Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isInterface()" because "typeToRead" is null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.bookstore.dto.AuthorDto com.bookstore.repository.AuthorRepository.findTopByGenre(java.lang.String)! Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isInterface()" because "typeToRead" is null
```

I tested the same code on spring-boot 2.1.4.RELEASE, it could work well.
I tried to find any official documents on this, but didn't find useful thread on this.

Comment: This is a [bug in Spring Data JPA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2408) and the fix will be released in a future version.

Comment: @ChinHuang, yes! that's exactly the same issue I met. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading Spring Boot 2.5.2 to 2.6.3 breaks all projection based JPA queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926645/upgrading-spring-boot-2-5-2-to-2-6-3-breaks-all-projection-based-jpa-queries)