# Spring Data Projections stopped working after spring update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, projection

So I updated the spring version to 2.6.3, which upgraded all the starters and spring data versions which brought a curious problem, the projections used for spring data stopped working and spring is throwing a NPE unless I explicitly provide `@Value("#{target.id}")` above the projection field. Problem is that you can't catch everything, and there is a good chance I miss something, so does anyone have an idea if there is a global solution to this or I should go for the downgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading Spring Boot 2.5.2 to 2.6.3 breaks all projection based JPA queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926645/upgrading-spring-boot-2-5-2-to-2-6-3-breaks-all-projection-based-jpa-queries)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, still same issue, I probably need a lower version of spring data.